# polymorphic relationship in ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have three models: **Company**, **Person**, and **Task**. A company has many people. A person has one company. A company has many tasks. A person has many tasks.

The task relationships are polymorphic.

Here are my models

```
App.Taskable = DS.Model.extend({

    tasks: DS.hasMany('task')
});

App.Task = DS.Model.extend({

    subject: DS.attr('string'),

    taskable: DS.belongsTo('taskable', { polymorphic: true})
});

App.Person = App.Taskable.extend({

  firstName: DS.attr('string'),

  lastName: DS.attr('string'),

  email: DS.attr('string'),

  company: DS.belongsTo('company'),

  fullName: function() {
    return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
  }.property('firstName', 'lastName')

});

App.Company = App.Taskable.extend({

    name: DS.attr('string'),

    people: DS.hasMany('person')
});
```

Notice that **Person** and **Company** extend **Taskable**. I believe i have these relationships defined properly. I don't know how to lazy load the tasks though.

Here is my person view

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='show/_person'>
    <div>
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <p class="form-control-static">{{fullName}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Company</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <p class="form-control-static">{{company.name}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tasks</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <p class="form-control-static">
          {{#each task in tasks}}
            {{task.subject}}<br />
          {{/each}}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </script>
```

A GET request is issued for the company associated with the person but no request is made for tasks. How do i get the tasks associated with a person or company? I would expect a GET request be made to `people/3/tasks` or something similar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that just the `ActiveModelAdapter` have implemented the polymorphic association.

To get this working you need to use the following format:

`GET /tasks`

```
{
    tasks: [
        {
            id: 1,
            subject: 'Mytask1',
            // in the polymorphic association we need to say the type and the id
            taskable: { type: "person", id: 1 }
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            subject: 'Mytask2',
            taskable: { type: "company", id: 1 }
        }
    ]
}
```

`GET /tasks/1`

```
{
    task: {
        id: 1,
        subject: 'Mytask1',
        // in the polymorphic association we need to say the type and the id
        taskable: { type: "person", id: 1 }
    }
}
```

I updated your sample in a fiddle please give a look http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/7k7RT/

Comment: thank you, that works great. However, I dislike how the task_ids have to be returned with the person model. What if i have a thousand tasks associated with a person? Making them all be returned with their associated model isn't going to work on that scale

Comment: You are welcome. I don't see problem with the task_ids, because is just an array of numbers. There is other option to load the tasks, you can use `links: { tasks: '/tasks/1' }` in your payload, where tasks is your property and '/tasks/1' is the endpoint where that data can be loaded. Give a look in the /people/1 mock, of that fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/Bm3Jy/

Comment: i think i broke your second fiddle. The polymorphic types are both Person